Operation 'sx' is not defined for this system
Any one knows how to resolve the below error:Operation 'sx' is not defined for this system. The below code works really well with ibm_sherbrooke but not with ibm_torino. I am presently getting the error as below:
It would be great if someone help me on this.
def find_transpiled_gate_delays(qc_transpiled: QuantumCircuit, backend):
    for gate in qc_transpiled.data:
        gate_name = gate.operation.name
        gate_qubits = [qc_transpiled.find_bit(qubit).index for qubit in gate.qubits]
        gate_delay = backend.instruction_durations.get(gate_name, gate_qubits)
      


service = QiskitRuntimeService()
 backend = service.backend('ibm_torino')
 pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level = 3)
 qc_transpiled = pm.run(qc_combine)
 find_transpiled_gate_delays(qc_transpiled, backend)

Edit 1 :
The below code do not work with ibm_torino but work with ibm_sherbrooke. I am using the latest version of qiskit==1.0.
import os
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from non_unitary_matrix_decomposition.polar_decomposition import polar_decomposition
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
import pdb
from encoding_techniques.encoding_techniques import c2q_encoding, qiskit_encoding
from pathlib import Path
from bqskit import compile
from bqskit.ext import bqskit_to_qiskit
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeBrisbane, FakeSherbrooke
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager

from qiskit import schedule, QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService




def find_transpiled_gate_delays(qc_transpiled: QuantumCircuit, backend):
    for gate in qc_transpiled.data:
        gate_name = gate.operation.name
        gate_qubits = [qc_transpiled.find_bit(qubit).index for qubit in gate.qubits]
        gate_delay = backend.instruction_durations.get(gate_name, gate_qubits)

def find_scheduled_circuit_time(qc_scheduled: QuantumCircuit, backend):
    schdl = schedule(qc_scheduled, backend)
    n_cycles_critical = schdl.duration
    cycle_time = backend.dt
    total_circuit_time = n_cycles_critical * cycle_time
    return n_cycles_critical, cycle_time, total_circuit_time





service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.backend('ibm_torino')
# backend = service.backend('ibm_sherbrooke')


qc_combine = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc_combine.sx(0)


pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level = 3)
qc_transpiled = pm.run(qc_combine)
find_transpiled_gate_delays(qc_transpiled, backend)

qc_scheduled = transpile(qc_transpiled, backend, scheduling_method='asap')

n_cycles_critical, cycle_time, theoretical_total_circuit_time = find_scheduled_circuit_time(qc_scheduled, backend)

print(n_cycles_critical)
print(cycle_time)
print(theoretical_total_circuit_time)

With ibm_torino, I am getting the error:
  File "/panfs/pfs.local/scratch/i2s/study/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/scheduler/lowering.py", line 178, in lower_gates
    raise QiskitError(
qiskit.exceptions.QiskitError: "Operation 'sx' on qubit(s) [51] not supported by the backend command definition. Did you remember to transpile your input circuit for the same backend?"


Can you put your full code, with imports, variables defined, etc... so that it's easy to reproduce the issue? In particular, it would help if simply changing your code from one backend to the other yields the error you describe.

Thank you @TristanNemoz for the response. I have edited the question. Please review.

What I understand is that ibm_torino donot provide the pulse level information because of which we cannot find its schdl = schedule(qc_scheduled, backend). So, the problem is not with sx, it is just with every gate. @TristanNemoz
